# Validation ControlTemplate string always appearing even when no Validation Error

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, xaml

I have created a style in order to specify the validation ControlTemplate to use when there is a validation error in some of my textboxes. The validation errors get caught, as I can see my style being used (the default red border for the textbox, and my added light pink background with a red "!!!" string), but the problem is the "!!!" red string is always there, even though there are no validation errors (though the pink background and red border disappear). I am using IDataErrorInfo in order to validation the textboxes.

Here is my xaml style code:

```
<Style x:Key="ErrorValidationTextBox" TargetType="{x:Type pres:OneTextBox}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightPink"></Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
    <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                    <AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Name="ControlWithError"/>
                    <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Right"
                                Foreground="Red"
                                FontSize="12pt"
                                FontWeight="Bold"
                                Margin="-18,0,0,0"
                                Text="!!!">
                    </TextBlock>
                </DockPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I tried adding this line to the < TextBlock > node but it didn't work:

```
Visibility="{Binding Validation.HasError, Source={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource BoolToHiddenOrVisibleConverter}}"
```

**My question is:** How can I make the "!!!" red string only appear when the Validation.HasError flag is set to true?

Here is how I declared one of my textboxes, as a reference. The OneTextBox is a control that encapsulates the regular WPF TextBox and adds some functionalities (as I am using a custom framework):

```
    <pres:OneTextBox Grid.Row="0" Watermark="Name..." Margin="85,12,0,0" Style="{StaticResource ErrorValidationTextBox}"
                     Text="{Binding Path=InterfaceSpecification.Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True}"
                     AcceptsReturn="False" MaxLines="1" Height="22" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                     HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="300" />
```

EDIT: I am getting the following binding error when running in debug:

```
BindingExpression path error: 'Validation' property not found on 'object' ''RelativeSource' (HashCode=58276509)'. BindingExpression:Path=Validation.HasError; DataItem='RelativeSource' (HashCode=58276509); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Visibility' (type 'Visibility')
```

EDIT2: Here is how I implement the IDataErrorInfo in my class:

```
    public string Error
    {
        get { return mError; }
        set { mError = value; }
    }

    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            switch (columnName)
            {
                case "Name":
                    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Name))
                    {
                        Error = "The name cannot be null, empty or contain only white spaces";
                    }
                    else if (Name.StartsWith(" "))
                    {
                        Error = "The name cannot start with a white spaces";
                    }
                    else if (Name.IndexOfAny(Path.GetInvalidPathChars()) != -1)
                    {
                        Error = "The name cannot contain invalid characters";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Error = null;
                    }
                    break;
            }

            return Error;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried using `Source={RelativeSource...` instead of `RelativeSource={RelativeSource....`

Comment: A quick way... just bind its visibility to something already getting toggled correctly.

Comment: @verdesrobert Could you post the full syntax of Source={RelativeSource... as I do not know of it. Im quite a beginner when it comes to WPF, I am starting to learn as I am advancing in this project

Comment: I am doing something similar in my code and I have the AdornedElementPlaceholder inside of a Border that is the last control in the DockPanel.  Try switching the AdornedPlaceHolder with the TextBlock in your code.

Comment: Just copied your code and made that little change `Visibility="{Binding Validation.HasError, Source={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource BoolToHiddenOrVisibleConverter}}"`

Comment: @ChrisW. If I understand what you are saying correctly, you are saying to bind the Visibility property on something else that is getting toggled when an error is detected? Unfortunately, there is nothing else appearing or disappearing when an error is detected other than that "!!!" red string.

Comment: @verdesrobert Unfortunately, that did not work. Though I added an error information in my original post that I had not noticed before. It cannot find the Validation.HasError property

Comment: what do you set to Error Property?

Comment: @verdesrobert I added the information you requested in my original post

Comment: I think i have the Solution For you

Comment: @verdesrobert Great! I hope that it will resolve the issue. What is your solution?

Comment: I was on my mobile so i couldn't write it i'm testing before giving you a wrong answer

Comment: Try using `Visibility="{TemplateBinding Validation.HasError,Converter={StaticResource BoolToHiddenOrVisibleConverter}}"`

Comment: @verdesrobert With this line in my TextBlock, the red "!!!" string never appears (whether I have a validation error or not). I do not have a binding error though. It is as though the Validation.HasError flag is always false, but my trigger for the LightPink background fires so it must be true sometimes.

Comment: Are you following this guide?
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15239/Validation-in-Windows-Presentation-Foundation

Comment: @verdesrobert Would there be a way to set the visibility property of my TextBlock in the trigger? If so, what would be the syntax to add to my trigger in order to do this?

Comment: I don't think so because the textblock to hide is inside a template, it's not the control itself

Comment: Surely working on Textblock

Visibility="{Binding ElementName=ControlWithError, 
                               Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.HasError),Converter={StaticResource CustomConverter}}">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is surely working

```
<Style x:Key="ErrorValidationTextBox" TargetType="{x:Type pres:OneTextBox}">
<Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightPink"></Setter>
    </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
<Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                <AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Name="ControlWithError"/>
                <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Right"
                            Foreground="Red"
                            FontSize="12pt"
                            FontWeight="Bold"
                            Margin="-18,0,0,0"
                            Text="!!!"
                            Visibility="{Binding ElementName=ControlWithError, Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.HasError),Converter={StaticResource BoolToHiddenOrVisibleConverter}}"   >
                </TextBlock>
            </DockPanel>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Comment: Is that really working for a DataGridROW?? or just jor the TextBox?? (I have the same problem but related to the row. Rendering the cell correctly works after error correction works well but afterwards the row keeps the red border and the '!' in the ControlTemplate.

Comment: What is the BoolToHiddenOrVisibleConverter doing..how does it look like??

Comment: It returns Visibility.Hidden or Visibility.Visible based on the value of the bool passed